# AVR C - step motor and adc code on Atmega32

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, avr, atmega

I am starting with microcontrollers and I am trying to code a voltage measurement of solar panel connected to Atmega32 (with external clock) microcontroller. The solar panel is mounted to the step motor for making the rotation of solar panel possible.

This is the part of my code (compilable):

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define B_0000  0
#define B_0001  1
#define B_0010  2
#define B_0011  3
#define B_0100  4
#define B_0101  5
#define B_0110  6
#define B_0111  7
#define B_1000  8
#define B_1001  9
#define B_1010  a
#define B_1011  b
#define B_1100  c
#define B_1101  d
#define B_1110  e
#define B_1111  f

#define _B2H(bits)  B_##bits
#define B2H(bits)   _B2H(bits)
#define _HEX(n)     0x##n
#define HEX(n)      _HEX(n)
#define _CCAT(a,b)  a##b
#define CCAT(a,b)   _CCAT(a,b)
#define BYTE(a,b)       HEX( CCAT(B2H(a),B2H(b)) )

#define STEPMOTOR_PORT PORTC
#define SOLAR_INPUT_PIN (1<<MUX2)|(1<<MUX0)

#define STEPMOTOR_STEP 8 // length of one step motor full step
#define STEPMOTOR_YZ_MAX_POSITION 6 // max stepmotor cw position
#define STEPMOTOR_YZ_MIN_POSITION -6 //max stepmotor ccw position

/* counterclockwise */
void inline stepmotor_yz_ccw_step()
{
    _delay_us(10000);
    STEPMOTOR_PORT = BYTE(0000, 0000);  
    _delay_us(10000);
    STEPMOTOR_PORT = BYTE(0001, 0000);  
    _delay_us(10000);
    STEPMOTOR_PORT = BYTE(0011, 0000);  
    _delay_us(10000);
    STEPMOTOR_PORT = BYTE(0010, 0000);  
    _delay_us(10000);
    STEPMOTOR_PORT = BYTE(0110, 0000);  
    _delay_us(10000);
    STEPMOTOR_PORT = BYTE(0100, 0000);  
    _delay_us(10000);
    STEPMOTOR_PORT = BYTE(1100, 0000);  
    _delay_us(10000);
    STEPMOTOR_PORT = BYTE(1000, 0000);  
    _delay_us(10000);

}

/* clockwise */
void inline stepmotor_yz_cw_step()
{
    _delay_us(10000);
    STEPMOTOR_PORT = BYTE(1000, 0000);  
    _delay_us(10000);
    STEPMOTOR_PORT = BYTE(1100, 0000);  
    _delay_us(10000);
    STEPMOTOR_PORT = BYTE(0100, 0000);  
    _delay_us(10000);
    STEPMOTOR_PORT = BYTE(0110, 0000);  
    _delay_us(10000);
    STEPMOTOR_PORT = BYTE(0010, 0000);  
    _delay_us(10000);
    STEPMOTOR_PORT = BYTE(0011, 0000);  
    _delay_us(10000);
    STEPMOTOR_PORT = BYTE(0001, 0000);  
    _delay_us(10000);
    STEPMOTOR_PORT = BYTE(0000, 0000);  
    _delay_us(10000);
}

unsigned int inline measure_voltage()
{
    ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC);  // Start conversion
    while (ADCSRA & (1 << ADSC)) ;  // wait for conversion to complete
    return ADCW;
}

void inline ports_init()
{
    DDRD = BYTE(1111, 1111);
    DDRC = BYTE(1111, 1111);
    PORTD = BYTE(1111, 1111);
    PORTC = BYTE(0000, 0000);
}

/* single measurement, ref voltage is 5V, division factor 32, PA5 port */
void inline adc_init()
{
    ADCSRA = (1 << ADEN) | (1 << ADPS2) | (1 << ADPS0);
    ADMUX = SOLAR_INPUT_PIN;
    ADMUX |= (1 << REFS0);
}

/* light led according to measured voltage */
void inline light_leds(unsigned int voltage)
{
    if (voltage < 128) {
        PORTD = BYTE(1111, 1110);
    }
    if (voltage > 128 && voltage < 256) {
        PORTD = BYTE(1111, 1101);
    }
    if (voltage > 256 && voltage < 384) {
        PORTD = BYTE(1111, 1011);
    }
    if (voltage > 384 && voltage < 512) {
        PORTD = BYTE(1111, 0111);
    }
    if (voltage > 512 && voltage < 640) {
        PORTD = BYTE(1110, 1111);
    }
    if (voltage > 640 && voltage < 768) {
        PORTD = BYTE(1101, 1111);
    }
    if (voltage > 768 && voltage < 896) {
        PORTD = BYTE(1011, 1111);
    }
    if (voltage > 896 && voltage < 1024) {
        PORTD = BYTE(0111, 1111);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int current_voltage = 0;
    unsigned int max_voltage = 0;
    int max_position = 0;
    int current_position = 0;
    int i = 0;
    ports_init();
    adc_init();

    while (1) {

            /* if not too far */
            if (current_position < STEPMOTOR_YZ_MAX_POSITION) {
                for (i = 0; i < STEPMOTOR_STEP; ++i)
                    stepmotor_yz_cw_step();

                current_position++;

            }
            _delay_ms(5000);

            current_voltage = measure_voltage();

            if (current_voltage > max_voltage)
            {
                max_voltage = current_voltage;
                max_position = current_position;
                light_leds(max_voltage);
            }       
    }
}
```

The problem is that, separately the voltage measurement and step motor rotation works. Even the rotation of two step motors works. ADC is working by itself also lighting leds, like above for max voltage, or for example for current voltage after each measurement. But when I mix those two together everything stops.

When i put them together like above, I think that the "too far" if is not even checking because step motor is not moving, and voltage measurement is not happening either.

When I make current_position as volatile the step motor starts rotating as expected, but it never stops, like the current_position is not incrementing itself at all. In that case adc measurement is not working.

Programator is FT232R Bitbang.

I am using this stepmotor and driver:
http://www.instructables.com/id/BYJ48-Stepper-Motor/

Solar panel volatage is 0-5V

I am testing it on starter kit (English version can be turned on by icons on top of page):
http://and-tech.pl/zestaw-evb-5-1/

Makefile:

```
F_CPU=16000000

CC=avr-gcc
CFLAGS=-mmcu=atmega32 -Wall -O2 -DF_CPU=$(F_CPU) -gstabs -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections

CXX=avr-g++
CXXFLAGS=$(CFLAGS)

OBJCOPY=avr-objcopy
AVRDUDE = -c ft232r -p m32 -P ft0 -B 19200 -U flash:w:"program.hex":a 

program:  main.o
    $(CXX) -o program main.o -I.

main.o: main.c 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c main.c -I. 

hex: program
    $(OBJCOPY) -O ihex program program.hex

upload: hex
    avrdude $(AVRDUDE)

clean:
    rm -f *.hex *.o *.s *.hex
```

I guess this is a code problem not hardware, because I was testing it on two different Atmega32 microcontroller to be sure everything is OK with it.

Thank You in advance for help!

Br, ruker

Comment: I doubt your code is well compiled. What's about important warnings like _undefined reference to_? Start changing declaration of all function to `static inline void your_function ( your parameters)`

Comment: Hmmm, the only warning I have got is about unused variable. Are You using any additional flag while compiling?

Comment: Style and program design remarks: get rid of those awful macros and use hex notation. Add comments explaining each write, alternatively use `#defined` bit masks instead of "magic numbers". Then use loops and look-up tables.

Comment: But using those BYTE macros makes easier to see which pin is set to high and which to low. In hex notation it is harder to tell it. BYTE(1111,0000) just set bits exactly like passed to it. What is wrong with that?

Comment: It is very hard for C programmers to read secret, home-brewed macros, but very easy for them to read hex. You can safely assume than any professional programmer has the ability to read hex "fluently". What it boils down to in this case though, is that you should have a look-up table containing the whole sequence and then simply loop across that table. Repetitive code is always a bad thing.

Comment: Just found this set of macros in stackoverflow, hehe. For me is more comfortable than hex notation, but ok I will fix it and edit the post with new code in couple of hours. Any ideas about main problem, why separately it is working but together not?

Comment: If supported you can use 0b notation for binary literals: `0x21`--> `0xb00100001`

Comment: Can you try removing "inline" from all the functions? I noticed a strange extra call to "stepmotor_yz_cw_step" and "light_leds" in the disassembly at the start of the code. This mysterious calls disappear when i either make `-O0` or remove the inlines. I am not sure of the reason for this and also not sure whether this will help you, just something you can try.

Comment: Also your `light_leds` function will fail to light any LEDs at the boundary values (256, 384, 512, etc). You need to modify your if condition to `if (voltage >= 128 && voltage < 256)` OR `if (voltage > 128 && voltage <= 256)`

Comment: Is your stepper motor running from the same (5v?) power source as the CPU  board?

Comment: Why are you compiling C code with a C++ compiler? Edit: Just realized this question was asked 7 years ago. What was the error?